# php strip off the first 10 numbers from a string and put the remaining in a new string

Tags: php, string, trim

I want to remove the first 10 numbers from a string and then take the remaining numbers in the original string and make that into a new string to use.

Example:

```
$org_string = '304928340912';
```

I think it is done with either a regex or the trim() function but dont know enough about them to define where to trim at the 10 number count from the beginning.

Result i am looking for would be (based on the org_string above):

```
$new_string = '12';
```

The number at the end could be 1, 2, 3, 4 digits long so i can just go off of the last x numbers.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Use `$new_string = substr($org_string, 10);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr).

```
$new_string = substr($org_string, 10);
```

Comment: `substr($org_string, 0, 10)` return `3049283409` not `12`

Comment: @Baba you're right! sorry, fixed.

Comment: This would return the first ten characters, `substr($org_string, 10)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I've edited my post already.

Comment: Have you tried the updated code above?

Comment: Yes this is working sorry for the miss i still had the ,0 from the first part.

Comment: Please select this as the answer by using the outlined checkmark.

Comment: I will when the time allows me to :)

Comment: Selected now, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_string = '';
if (strlen($org_string) > 10)
{
    $new_string = substr($org_string, 10);
}
echo $new_string;
```

otherwise we could obtain `false`

> substr  (PHP 4, PHP 5) Return part of a string
>
> Returns:   Type: string   Description: the extracted part of string;
>   or FALSE on failure, or an empty string.